# How to invoke a function in a component from a separate component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form input and a 'submit' button in two separate components **A** and **B**. How would I go about passing the input value from component **A** to the Redux store when the submit button in component **B** is clicked?

My thoughts:
 - I would have a *getFormInput* function in component **A** that would pass the input to the store (via a dispatch that has been mapped to props of component **A**). What I am not sure about is how to invoke *getFormInput* from a different component.

Comment: don't they have a parent component? :)

Comment: Yes, they are sibling components. Would you care to share your thinking? I am a bit new to react/ redux so I may need some extra promoting to pick up on what you are getting at :)

Comment: please check: [`lifting state up`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

Since you are talking about redux store, I suggest you to update the redux store on every textchange. That said, if you have entered 'a' in your text box, dispatch an action and update redux store. In this way, you would have consistent data across.

And when you click on your button, just invoke a method(may be another action) and there you can use getState().textBoxValuewhatever directly to access what you have entered in your textbox. (this would be possible as you are updating your redux store on every textchange)

Comment: This would certainly simplify things. A solution that only updates the store once when the submit button would be ideal but this would work so thank you.

Comment: I opted this because, you need not send any data in onclick methods. You can just use the redux store completely and send whatever you want through the click method there. If not, you can go ahead with lifting the stateup option as suggested in comments.